# What is the integral of the Zeta function from $-1$ to $i$?

Tags: complex-integration

I want to calculate
$$\int_{-1}^i \zeta(z) \, dz  $$
Using Wolframalpha gives me approx. $0.36$ while using Mathematica gives me approx. $0.07 - 0.28i$. Which of these is correct and why is there a difference?

Comment: WolframAlpha also gives the second answer if you click "more digits".  I'm guessing this is a bug with complex-valued integrals, it seems to be returning the sum of the absolute values of the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Is this a path-dependent integral in the complex plane?

Comment: I thought that Zeta is holomorphic and therefore the integral is path-independant. But I might be wrong?